correctAnswers in Surveyjs not working on completedBeforeHTML
I am using Surveyjs to set up a quiz but have this problem on the completed page:
When using the variable correctAnswers to show the number of correct answers on the completed page it does not work on completedBeforeHTML - but it works on completedHTML.
I set the property completedBeforeHTML like this: (as described in the docs https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/api-reference/survey-data-model#completedBeforeHtml)
"Thank you for running the quiz. You had {correctAnswers} correct answers. "
I expected the {correctAnswers} to show number of correct answers on completedBeforeHTML but it just shows 0.

You will need to write your own logic to store and retrieve the number of correct answers from previous quizzes. The easiest way would probably be to write it to a cookie.

Thanks. Yes I found out. Think I just remember this has worked earlier.

Ensure that you define the survey.data and set an existing user response to a survey.
survey.data = {
   "username": "Jane",
   "civilwar": "1861-1865",
   "libertyordeath": "James Madison",
   "magnacarta": "The foundation of the British parliamentary system"
};

I created this demo for your reference: View Plunker. You can run this quiz, and then re-run it to see that the Complete page appears as expected and shows the number of correct answers.
const json = {
  "cookieName": "quiz-survey",
  ...
  "completedBeforeHtml": "<h3>You got {correctAnswers} correct answers</h3>",
  "completedHtml": "<h3>You got {correctAnswers} correct answers</h3>",
//...


